# SonarQube scanner and Jenkins parallel build

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarlint, sonarscanner

I have two .NET solutions, one is in .NET 5 and other is in .NET Classic 4.7.2. Each solution has  separate Jenkins build job. Each job also analyze the solution using SonarQube's MSBuild scanner.

I am using SonarQube Server version 8.5
Scanner for .NET 5 `sonar-scanner-msbuild-5.1.0.28487-net5.0`
Scanner for .NET 4.7.2 `sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.10.0.19059-net46`

**Issue**
In Jenkins, When .NET 5 build is running, and at the same time if I execute another .NET Classic build then the latter one fails with the error

> C:\Users\jenkinsuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\15.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportBefore\SonarQube.Integration.ImportBefore.targets(62,5):
> error : The build is configured to run SonarQube analysis but the
> SonarQube analysis targets could not be located. Project:
> MyProject.csproj

I think the issue here is both scanners are sharing same location to store targets, so the latter one fails. I think have two options here

1>Is there anyway to run one job at a time in Jenkins without using any third party plugin? In Maven Project Configuration there is `# of executors` currently set to 3. Will changing this to 1 execute only one job at a time? Are there any side effects changing this value to 1.

2>In Sonar Scanner is there any property I can set on each scanner, so that scanner would use different location for targets

Answer (score 0):

Please consider global target installation as described in the [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-msbuild/#header-7):

> #### Concurrent Analyses on the Same Build Machine
>
> Concurrent analyses (i.e. parallel analysis of two solutions on the same build machine using a unique service account) are not supported by default by the Scanner for .NET. You can enable it as follows:
>
> 1. Locate the folder containing the Scanner for .NET
> 2. Go in the `Targets` folder and copy the folder `SonarQube.Integration.ImportBefore.targets`
> 3. Paste it under your build tool global ImportBefore folder (if the folder doesn't exist, create it).
>
> - For MSBuild, the path is `<MSBUILD_INSTALL_DIR>\<Version>\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportBefore` where `<MSBUILD_INSTALL_DIR>` is:
>
>   - For v14, default path is: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Microsoft.Common.Targets\ImportBefore`
>   - For v15, default path is: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportBefore` (for VS Community Edition)
>   - For v16, default path is: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Microsoft.Common.targets` (for VS Enterprise Edition)
> - For dotnet, the path is `<DOTNET_SDK_INSTALL_DIR>\15.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportBefore` where `<DOTNET_SDK_INSTALL_DIR>` can be found using the `dotnet --info` and looking for the Base Path property.
>
> The performance impact of this global installation for projects that aren't analyzed is negligible as this target is only a bootstrapper and will bail out nearly instantaneously when the `.sonarqube` folder is not found under the folder being built.